# An operator riddle

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, comparison, operators, imperative-programming

While converting a project from Python to C#, I found some interesting differences in the syntax families. Yet I got stuck, still unable to understand and comprehend the dissimilar behavior of **comparison operator** in C#.

During the course of curing this curiosity, I considered few languages of C-syntax family; C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript.. and verified the behavior. Here is how it transpired:

```
Let a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5;
```

Now, consider the following expressions:

```
a < a < a  // returns true
c < b < a  // returns true
c > b > a  // returns false
a < c > b  // returns false
```

If it was due to the [right-associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), then the following code in JavaScript shouldn't act like:

```
console.info(a < false);   // returns false
console.info(a < a);       // returns false
console.info(a < a < a);   // returns true, as opposed to returning false
```

Here is the C/C++ version

```
int main(){
    int a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5;

    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(a < a < a));  // returns true
    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(c < b < a));  // returns true
    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(c > b > a));  // returns false
    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(a < c > b));  // returns false

  return 0;
}
```

Except in Python, where

```
a < a < a  // returns false
c < b < a  // returns false
c > b > a  // returns true
a < c > b  // returns true
```

Can anyone explain why C-family of languages and Python are computing the expressions differently?

Comment: This question will be _much_ easier to follow if you write the examples using literals rather than variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [Python uses a slightly interpretation of your input](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Formally, if `a, b, c, ..., y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, ..., opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

This means your lines will be interpreted as

```
a < a < a = a < a and a < a // returns false
c < b < a = c < b and b < a // returns false
c > b > a = c > b and b > a // returns true
a < c > b = a < c and c > b // returns true
```

In C-style languages, an comparison expression will evaluate to either `false` (integer value 0) or `true` (integer value 1). So in C it will behave like

```
a < a < a = (a < a) < a = 0 < a  // returns true
c < b < a = (c < b) < a = 0 < a  // returns true
c > b > a = (c > b) > a = 1 > a // returns false
a < c > b = (a < c) > b = 0 > b // returns false
```

Note that almost all languages define operators with a boolean return value, but since boolean values can be implicit converted to zero or one the proposition above is still valid:

```cpp
// C++ example
struct myComparableObject{
    int data;
    bool operator<(const myComparableObject& o){
       return data < o.data;
    }
};

myComparableObject a, b;
a.data = 2;
b.data = 3;
int c = 5;

a < b; // true
a < c; // error, a cannot be converted to int / unknown operator
a.data < c; // true
a < b < c; // true, as this is equal to
           //   (a < b) < c = false < c = 0 < c
```

For example JavaScript will actually use `ToNumber` in order to compare two non-string objects, see [[ECMAScript p78](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), 11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm], where `ToNumber(false)` is zero and `ToNumber(true) === 1`.

> The comparison `x < y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces `true`, `false`, or `undefined`[...]
>
> - Let px be the result of calling ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
> - Let py be the result of calling ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).
>
>   1. If it is not the case that both Type(px) is String and Type(py) is String, then
>        `a.` Let nx be the result of calling ToNumber(px). Because px and py are primitive values evaluation 
>        order is not important.
>        `b.` Let ny be the result of calling ToNumber(py).
>        `c.` If nx is NaN, return undefined.
>        `d.` If ny is NaN, return undefined.
>        `e.` If nx and ny are the same Number value, return false.
>        `f.` If nx is +0 and ny is -0, return false. 
>        `g.` If nx is -0 and ny is +0, return false. 
>        `h.` If nx is +infty, return false. 
>        `i.` If ny is +infty, return true. 
>        `j.` If ny is -infty, return false. 
>        `k.` If nx is -infty, return true. 
>        `l.` If the mathematical value of nx is less than the mathematical value of ny —*note that these 
>        mathematical values are both finite and not both zero*— return true. Otherwise, return false.

Comment: Note that Javascript is slightly different again - a comparison returns a boolean, not an integer, but Javascript defines a sort order over types.

Comment: @NickJohnson, can you please explain the variant JavaScript behavior in comparison with C/C++/C#?

Comment: @vulcanraven: Added the specific parts from the ECMAScript docs.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `a < a < a` is evaluated like `((a < a) < a)` which then becomes `0 < a` which is true (when a >= 0)

If you run the following, the first expression changes to false.

```
int main(){
    int a=0, b=3, c=4, d=5;

    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(a < a < a));  // returns false
    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(c < b < a));  // returns true
    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(c > b > a));  // returns false
    printf("%s\n","false\0true"+6*(a < c > b));  // returns false

  return 0;
}
```

Whereas in Python, `a < a < a` becomes `a < a and a < a`. So it's not comparing the result of `a < a`.  If you add parentheses to your statements, you'll get the C-like behavior again.

```
(a < a) < a  ## returns true
(c < b) < a  ## returns true
(c > b) > a  ## returns false
(a < c) > b  ## returns false
```

Comment: I didn't realize that it would be evaluated from left to right as opposed to the case when we have assignment operator `c = a < b`. Thanks for elaborating your answer.